# Arduino Leonardo keyboard

Tags: arduino-leonardo

I use Arduino Leonardo board for virtual keyboard. Everything work fine, but when my local keyboard layout is russian it's not work how I want. This is my code

```
Keyboard.print("cmd");
typeKey(KEY_RETURN);
delay(2000);
Keyboard.print("powershell iwr -outf %TEMP%\\index.html http://google.com");
typeKey(KEY_RETURN);
```

Otput in English US keyboard layout:

```
cmd
powershell iwr -outf %TEMP%\index.html http://google.com
```

Output in Russian keyboard layout

```
сьв
зщцукырудд шцк -щгеа %ЕУЬЗ%\штвучюреьд реезЖ..пщщпдуюсщь
```

Is there a way to make Arduino Leonardo to write every time in English US keyboard layout no matter what keyboard layout uses my computer?

Comment: This is not really an Arduino question.  This is a Windows operating systems question about switching between keyboard layouts.  Should be close this question?  Or ask to have it moved to a more appropriate forum?

Answer (score 2):

The Arduino Leonardo, in the same way as any keyboard, just sends keystroke data. It is down to your computer's operating system to translate those into individual letters and symbols. The Leonardo (and indeed any keyboard) has no say over how the operating system does that translation.

A brief google search (which led back to Stack Exchange) found me [this project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20994/Using-multiple-keyboards-with-different-layouts-on) which may be of some interest. It allows you to automatically change the selected keyboard language depending on which keyboard is being used at any one moment in time.

Comment: But how to add this in Arduino Leonardo ?

Comment: You didn't quite grasp what I said, did you? It's down to *your operating system* which is *windows*, and *that* is where you have to do everything.

Comment: I understand you. But if I want to test arduino leonardo keyboard on different pc with russian layout I have to download this and use them. I want  to configure Arduino to send keystrokes everytime in US layout in every pc no matter which keyboard layout they uses.

Comment: @Desole you don't send keystrokes in any layout. You send keystrokes that, to a certain extent, describe the physical location of the key on they keyboard. There is no language. Only a location. Only the operating system can convert that location to a character. There is nothing you can do from the Arduino. No matter how much you beg and moan.

Comment: Think about it: if the keyboard could define the layout why would the operating system even have the ability to select a layout? It'd be pointless. Keycodes do not equate to characters directly. True, a Unicode keyboard is technically possible, but no operating system supports such a thing because there is no standard for it.